# Price of financial assets at $t=0$ in Black-Scholes framework

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, proof, homework

> Given the share price equation
> $$
> dS_t=rS_tdt+\sigma S_tdW_t
> $$
> working in the framework of Black-Scholes model, find the price at $t=0$ of the following two financial assets:
>
> (a) The asset pays at $t=T$ exactly $S_T^2$.
>
> (b) The asset pays at $t=T$ exactly $1$ if $S_T<K$, where $K$ is constant specified in the contract.

*My attempt at solution.*

(a) Since the solution of share price equation is given by
$$
S_t=S_0\,\text{exp}\left[\left(r-\tfrac12\sigma^2\right)t+\sigma W_t\right]
$$
we calculate using risk-neutral pricing
\begin{align}
C_0&=e^{-rT}\mathbb{E}_Q\left[C_T\right]\\
&=e^{-rT}\mathbb{E}_Q\left[S_T^2\right]\\
&=e^{(r-\sigma^2)T}S_0^2\,\mathbb{E}_Q\left[e^{2\sigma W_T}\right]\\
&=e^{(r-\sigma^2)T}S_0^2\,e^{2\sigma^2T} \\
&=e^{(r+\sigma^2)T}S_0^2\,\quad \text{(Answer)}
\end{align}

(b) Denoting by $\Theta(x)=\begin{cases}1, x\ge 0\\ 0, x<0\end{cases}$ the unit step function we find
\begin{align}
C_0&=e^{-rT}\mathbb{E}_Q\left[C_T\right]\\
&=e^{-rT}\mathbb{E}_Q\left[\Theta(K-S_T)\right]\\
&=e^{-rT}\,\mathbb{Q}\left\{S_T<K\right\}\\
&=e^{-rT}\,\mathbb{Q}\left\{\frac{S_T}{S_0}<\frac{K}{S_0}\right\}.
\end{align}
Denote $a=r-\tfrac12\sigma^2$, $b=\sigma\sqrt{T}$, $x=\frac{K}{S_0}$. Then $S_T/S_0=X$, $X\sim N(a,b^2)$ and
\begin{align}
\mathbb{Q}\left\{e^X<x\right\}&=\mathbb{Q}\left\{X<\ln(x)\right\}\\
&=\mathbb{Q}\left\{\frac{X-a}{b}<\frac{\ln(x)-a}{b}\right\}\\
&=\Phi\left(-\frac{\ln(1/x)+a}{b}\right)
\end{align}
where
$$
\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^xe^{-x^2/2}dx.
$$
Thus
$$
C_0=e^{-rT}\Phi\left(-\frac{\ln(S_0/K)+r-\tfrac12\sigma^2}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}\right)\quad \text{(Answer)}
$$

> **Question:** Is this solution correct?

Comment: Looks correct, except that in (a) $C_0=e^{(\color{red}{-}r+\sigma^2)T}S_0^2\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. but isn't there $2rT$ that comes from raising $S_T$ to the second power. Thus $-rT+2rT=+rT$ ?

Comment: Looks correct. My mistake.

Comment: Thanks.$\phantom{.................}$

Comment: Voting to reopen because the question is focused and specific enough, and OP also providers their own attempt at answering.